# Do kotlinx.coroutines.test.coroutines.runTest and JUnit's assertThrows go together?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin-coroutines

I have a test case that calls a suspend function (I'm working with kotlinx-coroutines). I want to assert that the function call fails with an exception. But in my IDE I get an error stating: "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body". With other assertions, like assertEquals, it works fine. What can I do to make this work?

Here is the code:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun `check that error is thrown`() = runTest { 
        val thrownEx: BadRequestException = Assertions.assertThrows(BadRequestException::class.java) {
            myService.mySuspendFun()
        }
        // do something with thrownEx
    }
```

Some setup information:

- Spring Boot 2.7.16
- Kotlin 1.9.10
- Kotlinx 1.7.3
- IDE: IntelliJ 2023.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `assertThrows` takes a second parameter of a non-suspending function type, but you are passing a lambda which includes a call to a suspending function. You need to wrap your suspending function inside a non-suspending function:

```
fun `check that error is thrown`() { 
    val thrownEx: BadRequestException = Assertions.assertThrows(BadRequestException::class.java) {
        runTest {
            myService.mySuspendFun()
        }
    }
    // do something with thrownEx
}
```